# Is there a name for a tag that closes itself?

Tags: html, xml, tags

In a tag based language like HTML or XML, there are tags which close themselves without the use of a second tag:

```
<tag/>
```

Rather than this:

```
<tag></tag>
```

Is there a specific name for tags that close themselves?

Thanks! :)

Comment: There was another answer here, but it has been removed. For reference, this kind of tag is often referred to as a 'self-closing tag'.

Comment: The HTML5 spec does not use the term "empty-element tag". Nor does it use the term "self-closing tag". It does however use the phrase "start tag that is marked as self-closing" and slight variants of several times. Note that in HTML5, the `/` only has any effect when parsing foreign content (i.e. SVG or MathML). In all other cases, it is ignored.

Comment: "start tag that is marked as self-closing" isn't terribly easy to say when you are explaining something that revolves around a start tag that is marked as self-closing. After mentioning the start tag that is marked as self-closing a few times, you are going to wish there was a single word for the start tag that is marked as self-closing. :P

Saying empty-element tag, or self-closing tag is a little better. I guess I'll have to go with those in the future! This question was here to see if there was a better alternative - guess not!

@Alohci Thanks for the info.

Comment: Just as an aside, I think the reason HTML5 does not use "empty-element tag" is that the relationship between tags and elements is much more complicated in HTML than in XML. For example, imagine a file whose entire contents are `<isindex/>` Parsed as XML, it returns a DOM with one element called "isindex" with no content. Parsed with an HTML5 parser, it returns a DOM with eight elements, four of which have content, four of which are empty, and none of which is called "isindex"!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [XML specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/) refers to them as **empty-element tags**.

[Source](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-starttags):

> Definition: An element with no content is said to be empty.] The
>   representation of an empty element is either a start-tag immediately
>   followed by an end-tag, or an empty-element tag. [Definition: An
>   empty-element tag takes a special form:]